# MySQL select sum of different rows in 1 row

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table with multiple names of persons. Each person appears several times on several dates on several jobs. I want to select distinct persons with sum of working hours per different job.
Example :

```
PersonName     Job1     Job2     Job3

  Eliot        14:55    23:17     80:12
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Pls post your query, table structure and sample data

Comment: "Appears several times on several dates" doesn't really help us help you. How do you know how much time he worked a day? starttime endtime columns ? a column that specify the amount? can a person work after midnight ? Please post table structures and attempts.

Answer (score 0):

You should store the working time as minutes (e.g. integer) or as hours (e.g. decimal) to be able to calculate a sum. In that case you could use the following code:

```
SELECT PersonName, SUM(Job1) as Job1, SUM(Job2) as Job2, SUM(Job3) AS Job3
FROM schema_name.table_name
GROUP BY PersonName;
```

Right now your working time seems to be stored as a string. You could write a query that takes that into account but it should be much easier to store the working time as a number.